# Sticky header(row) and column in table without any jQuery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, sticky

I have a requirement where I need to stick the first row(header) and first two columns of the table while scrolling horizontally and vertically.

I did previously  with a Jquery plugin([link to plugin](https://github.com/lai32290/TableHeadFixer))  which worked quite good, but the problem was when number of rows increases like around 1000 rows, while binding the browser tab get freeze and end up in unresponsive page.

So I am looking for a CSS solution where I could achieve the same.
I need the table cells to be dynamic, so the width of the table cell should increase according to the content and do not mess up with the structure of the table.

Here is a fiddle with table structure [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8dhoyun4/). So is there any way where I can freeze header and columns without any heavy plugin  and altering the table structure?

Comment: You can try `slickGrid` (https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid). But its end of support.
Also, i tried to handle by CSS but not success. The simple way i solved by myself is get width of column and set to header. 
With requirement: lazy loading(rendering), and void to altering table structure quite hard to find an plugin adapt your expectation.

Comment: @ManhLe thanks . i would try this solution. . but i am not sure how much it will help in case of  large number of rows.

Comment: As my recommended, `slickGrid` render visible part, so browser freeze can be solve. But when you drag the scroller fast, the table display white (because didn't rendered).
If you come to other lib like `DataTables`, i think it will help you a lot. But table structure will be modify.
Please take a look at https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/defer_render.html

Comment: @ManhLe before i had issue like when i bind  more than 400 rows whole window crashes.

Comment: which plugin did you try?

Comment: https://github.com/lai32290/TableHeadFixer

Comment: sorry, i didn't try TableHeadFixer before.

Comment: its good. and change according to its width. only problem is there when comes to large number of data

Comment: Please edit the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
table tr > th:first-child,
table tr > td:first-child {
      position: sticky;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
}
```